# ECSlidingDrawer theming and animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, slidingmenu

so I have an app and I have a sliding drawer on the left that can be pulled out/revealed by a button tap or a gesture. It looks like [this](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/957fadf085bdae9513ec55e668ddb3b0f26f9475/687474703a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f782e636f6d2f752f31303933373233372f72657665616c2e706e67).

I wanted to animate the drawer so it had a folding animation kind of similar to [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/543645-UX-iOS-UI-iPhone-idea-with-video-process?list=searches&tag=app_ui).

I have looked around the internet extensively and didn't find anything.

Does anyone know whether this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (SCNR)

Comment: okay... how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article describes the folding animation using CATransfromLayer. I think this might help.
http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/tag/catransformlayer/

Comment: I came across the following libraries which might be useful.https://github.com/xyfeng/XYOrigami and https://github.com/geraldhuard/YFoldView